# i applied a sum on a groupby and i want to sort the result

Tags: python, pandas

I did : `g=df.groupby('name of the column')` and i got a group. Now I want to, for every different 'name of the column', sum values that are specified in another column. So when i run the function, i'll get a  series(sorted by sum of values) with each 'name of the column' and its respective sum of the values . What i did was:

```
for name, dfaux in g:   
    print(name, dfaux['name of the column where the values are specified'].sum())
```

I did get the series that I wanted, but I don't know how to sort it. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Please share a sample of dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Do u want the below kind of sorting, if yes u can code so.
your data-frame

```
0    a     1

1    b     2

2    a     3

3    c     4

4    b     5
```

If u expect the output to be

```
a        4

c        4

b        7
```

```
d = {'col1':['a','b','a','c','b'], 'col2':[1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df.groupby(['col1']).sum().sort_values(by=['col2']))
```

here groupby will return a data-frame with the column names as specified before.
so u can just sort the returned data-frame.